# Creating a calculated column for indexing in DBVis

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table containing the websites a user visited, their timestamps, and the user ID associated with it. I want to create a column which contains indexing for the order of the websites visited, but I want it to reset back to 1 when I move on to the next user. Example:

```
         URL                  |  UID  |          Time       |Index
www.google.com/               |  1234 | 2020-01-12 17:52:51 |  1
www.google.com/doodles/about  |  1234 | 2020-01-12 17:53:20 |  2
www.amazon.com/               |  4321 | 2020-01-12 13:57:02 |  1
www.amazon.com/gp/bestsellers/|  4321 | 2020-01-12 13:57:18 |  2
```

Would this be possible?

Comment: Please tag the question with the *database* you are using.  The GUI connecting to the database is much less important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `row_number()`:

```
select t.*, row_number() over (partition by uid order by time) as seqnum
from t;
```

The `partition by` handles the part about resetting the count to `1` for the "next user".